# Read Timeout error while making an API Inbound call to Salesforce

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, metadata-api

Getting Read Timeout error while making an API Inbound call to Salesforce.

Is it possible to check at  Salesforce is receiving connections.

Comment: Whats the timeout value set in your HTTP call?

Answer (score 0):

Setup => Manage Users => Login History

Answer (score 0):

Default timeout value is 10 seconds if you haven't set any. You can check your call via POSTMAN(REST CALLS) or SOAPUI (SOAP)calls to get exact idea about how much time your salesforce service is taking to respond. Maximum you can set this timeout to be 120 seconds.